# MS Access - Age of record calculated field

Tags: sql, ms-access, calculated-field, date-difference

I am new to Access but I have experience with Excel and Power BI. I could use a little help with what is probably a very simple problem for most of you.

I searched for a simple solution to this same problem quite extensively before posting here. I tried adapting solutions for similar problems to my problem, but I'm just not familiar enough with Access yet to bridge that gap.

I have a [request date] field. I want my [age] field to return the number of days since that request date. Sounds simple enough. o_O

Through trial and error I eventually determined that I cannot do this without a query (please prove me wrong?). And why can't I use datediff() or date() in a calculated field, anyway? Grr.

So I set up an update query for a new field (called [today]) with the expression "date()".

Then I set the [age] field to be calculated with the expression [today]-[request date].

This gives me the result I want for [age]. But now I'm thinking I need to write an autoexec macro to run this query every time the database is opened so that [today] stays current.

At this point I stopped. Seems like a lot of work for such a simple problem. I hate being inefficient. I'm hoping someone out there knows a more elegant solution that might also teach me some new tricks, too.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Table Calculated field is limited in what functions are available to it. Just the way it is. You should not update table with current date. You should calculate age when needed via expression in query or in textbox.

Comment: For my own understanding, it would be helpful if you could explain why i "should not update table with current date." What is the risk with this approach?

Comment: The risk is that someone neglects to run the update and wrong data is used (as you surmised, could automate this update when database opens but why bother with this complication?). Either way you have to build an SQL statement. It is a commonly accepted principle of db management that saving data dependent on other data (aka calculated data) is usually a bad idea. If someone exported the table data then the [today] field would not maintain currency for that exported set of data.

Comment: Also, if this is a multi-user split db, each user opening db would trigger update but if other users have table in use, update would likely fail anyway.

Comment: Thank you, these are good points that I would not have thought about until there was an issue. It is so much better for someone's education when you tell them the WHY that goes along with the DO's and DONT's.

Answer (score 1):

[Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

Just use a SELECT query. It could be as simple as

```
SELECT *, DateDiff("d",[request date],Date()) AS Age
FROM yourTable
```

and then use that query wherever you would use the table.

Comment: I'll try to research SELECT query a bit so I can maybe understand your answer. I'm not sure what you mean by "use that query wherever you would use the table" though. I want the data to appear in the actual table.

Comment: Use query as data source for forms and reports.

Comment: I do not need this AGE data for any form or report, I just need it in the table. I'd rather not build extra reports, forms, etc. to convey this information in a meeting when the table itself is already perfect for our meetings (we filter some columns and sort others, including age). I'm slow with Access as a new user, and I don't have a lot of time to build an elaborate interface. That's why I was hoping to just use the main table like this.

Comment: Use query for your meeting presentation. As advised, use query for whatever you would use table.

Comment: I guess I'm on my own again. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Whoa. In your question you stated you wanted to learn things. SELECT queries are really the 2nd most basic thing in any relational database (after tables), you cannot do much without them. I really have no idea what the issue is. @KYLEKYLEBOBYLE